# C++ pointers and references to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm reading the C++ Primer 5th Edition, and it has a part that shows us the following code:

```
 int *p; int *&r = p;
```

What is the meaning of `*&`, I can't understand!

Comment: pointer to the address of r.

Comment: _@Luiz_ It would be more helpful to answer your question correctly, if you show the exact type definitions for `r` and `p`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ r is reference and p pointer

Comment: And they are both integer

Comment: If `r` is an `int&` and `p` is an `int*`, then this doesn't compile.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what's the meaning of &* together.

Comment: In Cpp primer they wrote something like this:
int *p;
int *&r = p;

Comment: @Luiz There is no _together_ these are both operator operations on their own, which have to be sequentially from right to left.

Comment: @LuizFernando, Perhaps unfortunate, that's a completely different piece of code. Your question concerns taking variables and applying operators to them. This code concerns initializing a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from (your nicely clarifying) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223409/c-pointers-and-references#comment89427374_51223409), that this is the full code you see

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int *p; int *&r = p;
}
```

in that book.
`p` is a pointer to `int`, `int *&r` declares `r` as a reference to an `int` pointer, and must be initialized with such (`= p`).

---

Another comment of yours mentions

> [*"I'm just trying to understand what's the meaning of `&*` together."*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223409/c-pointers-and-references-to-pointers/51223603?noredirect=1#comment89427362_51223409)

You need to distinguish, if the context of that code is met from a *pointer variable reference* initialization, or assigning to a de-referenced pointer value.

The former (initialization form) can be used at local scope as demonstrated.

The usage in a plain statement (as e.g. with a function parameter)

```
void foo(int i) {
    int j = *&i; 
}
```

just applies two (three) separate operations:

1. `&` operator taking an address.
2. `*` de-referencung an address (much like `->`)
3. `=` copying the right site evaluation to the left site expression (likely to be elided code from the compiler, if conditions allow it)

Comment: Guys, this is the correct answer. You must read from right to left. Pointer to reference is illegal. *& is reference to a pointer.

Comment: @Volt: No, this was not the original code written in the question.

Comment: @Acorn Well, if we need clarifications for questions we can ask in comments. If the user is new, we can help them about how to add this additional information. Playing FGITW probably isn't the best game to play here.

Comment: Thank you @πάνταῥεῖ , I'm a new user of stackoverflow, and English is not my dominant language, sorry about the mistakes. Thx :)

Comment: @LuizFernando No problem, you're welcome. Though correct reference and evidence is an essential thing expected from attending learners in a professional manner, it's not necessarily obvious what actions should be done from your site to clarify your question.
Hopefully I've shown you a way out from this obstacle asking a good question at this site.